# Hide / Show Column depending on select

Tags: angularjs

I use *ng-hide* and a selectbox to hide/show columns of my table .

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td ng-hide="myOption=='one'"><input ng-hide="myOption=='one'"></input></td>
     <td ng-hide="myOption=='one' || myOption=='two' "><input ng-hide="myOption=='one' || myOption=='two' "></input></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody> 
</table>
<select ng-model="myOption">
    <option value="one">test1</option>
    <option value="two">test2</option>
    <option value="three">test3</option>
</select>    
</div>
```

It works well.

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate it: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marmuel/TKTn5/)

**Question**

How can I clear the values of the hidden input to avoid errors in my calculation? In jQuery i know the solution, but I want to learn AngularJS

Comment: Take a look at my Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-change="[second='', first='']"` to clear out the input fields, otherwise if you want more functionality to be done at the time of on-change use a function call at `ng-change="someFunction()"`

simply if you want to clear the input field which you have shown in jsfiddle you can try this

**[Working Code](http://jsfiddle.net/wF6xw/)**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td ng-hide="myOption=='one'"><input ng-model="first" ng-hide="myOption=='one'"></input></td>
     <td ng-hide="myOption=='one' || myOption=='two' "><input ng-model="second" ng-hide="myOption=='one' || myOption=='two' "></input></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody> 
</table>
<select ng-model="myOption" ng-change="[second='', first='']">
    <option value="one">test1</option>
    <option value="two">test2</option>
    <option value="three">test3</option>
</select>    
</div>
```